# how to convert milliseconds to Relative time?

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) ,

I want to convert milliseconds to relative time

Received from Database : 1423554515215

I wanna convert it to something like : ( 1 min ago )  OR  ( 5 years ago )

**UPDATE**

exactly Like stackoverflow post or comment timing

Comment: Simple `new Date(1423554515215)` will do, Why do you need momentjs

Comment: I want relative time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
moment(new Date(1423554515215)).fromNow()
```

Gives `"36 minutes ago"` right now.